# Xamarin form :How to search in listview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have listview containing data from web API. I want to search in the listview with character wise. The problem I am facing is when I start searching, it works fine but it gets very very slow. I need some solution to fix it. Here is my code:

```cs
private async void Entry_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();

    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(" http://172.16.4.212:51583/api/GetItems");

    var admtPatients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<tblItem>>(json);
    ObservableCollection<tblItem> trends = new ObservableCollection<tblItem>(admtPatients);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(medicine.Text))
    {
        MyListView.ItemsSource = trends;
    }
    else
    {
        MyListView.ItemsSource = trends
            .Where(x => 
                x.strItemName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLowerInvariant()) || 
                x.strItemName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToUpperInvariant()));
    }

    //await ((MainViewModel)this.BindingContext).LoadCountNotificationAsync();
}
```

Comment: Cache the results of "GetItems" and search through the cache rather than making a new request for each letter typed :o

Comment: how to cache the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time `Entry_TextChanged` is triggered, the call to `GetStringAsync` is done, which is very time consuming. This means that whenever the user **presses a key** a call to the API is made. This is why it is so slow.

You are better off calling `GetStringAsync` in the page's `OnAppearing` (for example), and saving the result globally:

```cs
private List<tblItem> listOfTableItems = new List<tblItem>();

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://172.16.4.212:51583/api/GetItems");
    listOfTableItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<tblItem>>(json);
}
```

Then, in your `Entry_TextChanged` you reference `listOfTableItems` from the examples above:

```cs
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.NewTextValue))
{
    MyListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<tblItem>(listOfTableItems);
}
else
{
    MyListView.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<tblItem>(listOfTableItems
        .Where(x => x.strItemName.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(e.NewTextValue.ToLowerInvariant())));
}
```